# Configuring Apache to run Jenkins on localhost/jenkins instead of localhost:8080

Tags: apache, jenkins

I installed Jenkins on my Windows PC with Windows Installer. It ran successfully in localhost:8080 but I wanted to run in localhost/jenkins or jenkins.localhost. I tried adding the following virtual host to my http-vhost.conf but it doesnt work.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName jenkins.localhost
    ServerAlias jenkins.localhost
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a virtual host and routed it there and that fixed the issue.